# not update the sign-up page despite of successful migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to ruby on rails and stuck with this problem.While i am using Devise created the sign-up form which worked. later i want to add another text field of user name in it. I run this command  `rails generate migration add_user_name_to_members user_name:string` and then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

which worked but when I restart the server and load the sign up page. It showed me the old content any help will me appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this what it needs to be since you are adding an extra column to your existing table. Try this.

1.`rails g migration AddColumnsToMembers provider user_name`

2.`rake db:migrate`

And You have to manually makes changes on sign-up page.

Answer (score 0):

By default devise will accept the email and password for sign up process. If you need to add an extra field to it you need to customize your devise views. 
Also if you add an extra column to your table it wont get affected in your devise sign up view.